# javafx gui update strategy with bidirectionalbinding

Tags: user-interface, binding, javafx

I'm looking for a proper update strategy for a gui element (in my case with javafx, TextField) which is linked to a variable of a configuration class. 
These rules have to be fullfilled:

1) If I set the variable in the config class the gui element(textfield) needs to refresh

2) If I change the textfield the variable in the config class needs to refresh

3) If and only if the variable in the config class is changed, due to the textfield change, some action has to be taken. 

4) If I change the variable in the config, I don't want that the action is taken (i.e. the listener to be notified).

Assume something like this:

```
Gui.java
public TextField textField = new TextField();



Config.java
public StringProperty stringProperty = new StringProperty();
stringProperty .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
            System.out.println("config string changed").

        }
    });


  public void update(){
    // now this is causing the problem because the listener
    // will know about this set() obviously
    stringProperty.set("bad idea");
  }


Controller.java
Gui gui = new Gui();
Config config = new Config();

// setup connection between gui element and config
gui.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(config.stringProperty);
```

I am aware of the fact that I could remove the changeListener before setting the value and afterwards adding it again, but I'm wondering if there is a proper solution for issues like this.

**EDIT**:
In fact what I need to know: is the changed() called because of the binding or because of the set(). If this is somehow possible, my problem would be solved.

Thanks!

Cheers!

Comment: Can you clarify (3) a little? Do you want this action to happen on each change of the text in the text field (i.e. each key press, etc), or only when the user "commits" a change (e.g. by pressing enter)?

Comment: I want to get every change. This works quite well with the bidirectional binding. My only concern is about the set() which "fires" the listener. I edited the code to clarify that the update method can be called from some other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always mimic a bidirectional binding with a pair of listeners:

```
StringProperty a = new SimpleStringProperty("");
StringProperty b = new SimpleStringProperty("");

a.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    b.set(newValue);
});

b.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    a.set(newValue);
});
```

The `set` methods in the property classes are smart enough to check if the value is really being changed before notifying any listeners, so you don't get into problems of infinite recursion here (though you need to be very careful if you do this with floating point types).

This helps you, because the state of the "other" property can help determine how you got to the listener code. Consider calling

```
a.set("update");
```

In this scenario we have:

1. `a` and `b` are both empty strings
2. We call `a.set("update")`
3. `a` changes its value to `"update"`, `b` is still an empty string
4. Since `a` has changed, its listener is invoked with `oldValue=""` and `newValue=a.get()="update"`. Note that `b.get()` returns a value different to `newValue`
5. `a`'s listener invokes `b.set("update")`, so now `a` and `b` are both `"update"`
6. Since`b` has changed, its listener is invoked with `oldValue=""` and `newValue="update"`. Note that in this case, `a.get()` returns the same value as `newValue`.
7. `b`'s listener invokes `a.set("update")`, which is a no-op (as `a` already has that value).

So now you can write the listeners as follows:

```
a.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (b.get().equals(newValue)) {
        // change to a occurred via a change to b
    } else {
        // change to a occurred via a call to a.set(...)
        b.set(newValue);
    }
});

b.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (a.get().equals(newValue)) {
        // change to b occurred via a change to a
    } else {
        // change to b occurred via a call to b.set(...)
        a.set(newValue);
    }
});
```

In your specific example you can do something like:

```
gui.textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> 
    config.stringProperty().set(newText));
```

and

```
config.stringProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
    if (gui.textField.getText().equals(newText)) {
        System.out.println("Text field was changed to: "+newText);
    } else {
        gui.textField.setText(newText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi James_D, I appreciate your suggestions, however they will force me to implement the processUserTextUpdate()-method in the class which contains the gui element. I'd rather like a solution, where I can put my listeners on the config properties, as they are a central point, whereas the gui components can be in different classes. I think the solution should go in the direction that when I set the stringProperty.set() the changelistener should not be called.

Comment: In fact what I need to know; is the change() called because of the binding or because of the set(). If this is somehow possible, my problem would be solved.

Comment: Changed answer to clarify.

Comment: Still, the problem is that I would need to know each gui element in the config class. However, I do know it to some extend because I need to bind the elements anyway.